# Vulcans (Star Trek, preferably original)- Can they have eye colors such as blue or green?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Reference for a story- wondering about certain characteristics. Is there any physical characteristic that would be considered a stigma in Vulcan society also?

Comment: Being human is considered a stigmatic physical characteristic in Vulcan society.

Comment: @Valorum I think the inclusion of "also" in the OP's question implies that blue/green eyes are a stigma in human culture, and the OP is wondering about analogous stigmata in Vulcan culture. I don't think humans are a part of Vulcan culture.

Comment: @BMF - Human/Vulcan hybrids most certainly are a part of Vulcan society.

Comment: the physical ability to perform mind-melds was at one point anathema

Comment: @Valorum Good point. That's probably the best known stigma from Vulcan culture. It's the only one I can think of, it'd be interesting to know if there are others.

Comment: Vulcans can have whatever color eyes the actor cast for the role has. (see, of course, Saavik, as mentioned in LogicDictates' excellent answer).  Tech capabilities to fit the plot.  Physical characteristics to fit the actors.

Comment: @Basya I guess that was necessarily true until the real-world invention of colored contact lenses made it possible to change the eye color of the actors.  Just like Geordi's robot eye-transplants weren't possible at the beginning of TNG until they had the CGI to do that in the movies.

Comment: Do you want to know about stigmas, or about eye colours? This is two questions in one.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I haven't noticed that they do that in Star Trek, even if it is possible.  Vulcans have whatever eye colors end up being available in actors

Comment: @akveritas - Just wondering: do you believe my answer has fully addressed your question/s? If so, would you mind marking it as accepted, by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting buttons? (And upvoting it as well, if you haven't already?) I'd appreciate it, and I did invest a fair bit of time and effort into that answer.

Answer (score 10):

## Vulcans can certainly have blue eyes...

Some may also have green eyes, but the only example I can think of is [Saavik](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Saavik), when she was portrayed by Kirstie Alley in [Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_II:_The_Wrath_of_Khan).

[image]

Saavik had *brown* eyes when she was portrayed by Robin Curtis in [Star Trek III: The Search for Spock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_III:_The_Search_for_Spock) and [Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home), and was [stated to be "half Vulcan and half Romulan"](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/twok.txt) in one of the scripts for *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan* (though this was never mentioned within canon), so this example seems a bit iffy on more than one count.

[image]

We've seen quite a few Vulcans with blue eyes though, including at least one from *Star Trek: The Original Series* (if that's what you meant by "original"). The examples below are listed in order of appearance.

[Stonn](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stonn) (TOS: "[Amok Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Amok_Time_(episode))")

[image]

[Satelk](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Satelk) (TNG: "[The First Duty](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_First_Duty_(episode))")

[image]

[T'Pan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/T%27Pan) (TNG: "[Suspicions](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Suspicions_(episode))")

[image]

[T'Lara](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/T%27Lara) (DS9: "[Rules of Engagement](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rules_of_Engagement_(episode))")

[image]

[Sitak](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sitak) (DS9: "[Favor the Bold](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Favor_the_Bold_(episode))")

[image]

[Solok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Solok_(Vulcan)) (DS9: "[Take Me Out to the Holosuite](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Take_Me_Out_to_the_Holosuite_(episode))")

[image]

[V'Lar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/V%27Lar) (ENT: "[Fallen Hero](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fallen_Hero_(episode))")

[image]

[V'Las](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/V%27Las) (ENT: "[The Forge](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Forge_(episode))", "[Awakening](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Awakening_(episode))", "[Kir'Shara](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kir%27Shara_(episode))")

[image]

Regarding the question about stigma, there are obviously various *behaviors* which would be stigmatised within Vulcan society, subject to specific eras (mind melds were stigmatised during the 22nd century, but not in the 23rd and 24th centuries). I don't recall hearing of any *physical* characteristics possessed by any Vulcans which would be stigmatised in that way though.

Comment: As an addendum, we know from TOS that Romulans can have blue eyes -- the centurion in *Balance of Terror* (played by [John Warburton](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/John_Warburton)) did. Given that Vulcans and Romulans are effectively the same species...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Good call. Come to think of it, the Vulcan, [Stonn](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stonn), from "[Amok Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Amok_Time_(episode))" had blue eyes too. I'll edit that into my answer.

Comment: Gah! Of course he did! I remember noting it when I first saw that ep...

Comment: On the Romulan/Vulcan thing, Robin Curtis's Saavik was Vulcan but Kirstie Alley's Saavik was half-Romulan. (Similarly, Where no man has gone before Spock had a distant human ancestor, but subsequent Spock was half-human)

Comment: @Graham Lee - I don't believe Saavik was ever established as half-Vulcan canonically, but according to [her page on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Saavik), she was stated to be half-Vulcan, half-Romulan in one or more of the scripts for _Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan_, and half-Vulcan in a script for _Star Trek III: The Search for Spock_. And yeah, Spock did claim one of his "ancestors married a human female" in the second TOS pilot, but canonically we now know that was true of his parents.

Comment: "Robin Curtis's Saavik was Vulcan but Kirstie Alley's Saavik was half-Romulan." Citation needed; they're the *same character*.

Comment: Obviously, @RussellBorogove, since Kirstie herself is half-Romulan... :)

Comment: It appears that sometime between TOS and TNG, Vulcan instituted an official haircut policy. It was the only logical thing to do.